# error in grails 3.2

Tags: grails, velocity, grails-3.0

I am using my grails project and out of nowhere I have started getting the following error. I have tried trouble shooting as well as reverting the project to last known working git version and I still can not get rid of this exception

```
    ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function defineProperty in object function Object() { [native code for Object.Object, arity=1] }
. (Base script#9)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3557)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3535)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3563)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3582)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3646)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2186)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c448(Base script:9)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c447(Base script:9)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c388(Base script:9)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c216(Base script:3)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c3(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c1(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c0(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:401)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3003)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.exec(Base script)
    at com.craigburke.asset.JavaScriptRunner.<init>(JavaScriptRunner.groovy:20)
    at com.craigburke.asset.JavaScriptEngine.run(JavaScriptEngine.groovy:35)
    at com.craigburke.asset.JavaScriptEngine$run$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at com.craigburke.angular.AnnotateProcessor.process(AnnotateProcessor.groovy:27)
    at asset.pipeline.AbstractAssetFile.processedStream(AbstractAssetFile.groovy:164)
    at asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor.fileContents(DirectiveProcessor.groovy:307)
    at asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor$fileContents$4.call(Unknown Source)
    at asset.pipeline.AssetPipeline.serveUncompiledAsset(AssetPipeline.groovy:65)
    at asset.pipeline.AssetPipelineFilter.doFilterInternal(AssetPipelineFilter.groovy:175)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
```

...

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
    org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function defineProperty in object function Object() { [native code for Object.Object, arity=1] }
    . (Base script#9)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3557)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3535)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3563)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3582)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3646)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2186)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c448(Base script:9)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c447(Base script:9)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c388(Base script:9)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c216(Base script:3)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c3(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c1(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c0(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:401)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3003)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.exec(Base script)
        at com.craigburke.asset.JavaScriptRunner.<init>(JavaScriptRunner.groovy:20)
        at com.craigburke.asset.JavaScriptEngine.run(JavaScriptEngine.groovy:35)
        at com.craigburke.asset.JavaScriptEngine$run$2.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at com.craigburke.angular.AnnotateProcessor.process(AnnotateProcessor.groovy:27)
        at asset.pipeline.AbstractAssetFile.processedStream(AbstractAssetFile.groovy:164)
        at asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor.fileContents(DirectiveProcessor.groovy:307)
        at asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor$fileContents$4.call(Unknown Source)
        at asset.pipeline.AssetPipeline.serveUncompiledAsset(AssetPipeline.groovy:65)
        at asset.pipeline.AssetPipelineFilter.doFilterInternal(AssetPipelineFilter.groovy:175)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
    org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function defineProperty in object function Object() { [native code for Object.Object, arity=1] }
    . (Base script#9)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3557)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3535)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3563)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3582)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3646)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2186)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c448(Base script:9)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c447(Base script:9)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c388(Base script:9)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c216(Base script:3)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c3(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2347)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:272)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:127)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c2(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c1(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:66)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1._c0(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:401)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3003)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.call(Base script)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c1.exec(Base script)
        at com.craigburke.asset.JavaScriptRunner.<init>(JavaScriptRunner.groovy:20)
        at com.craigburke.asset.JavaScriptEngine.run(JavaScriptEngine.groovy:35)
        at com.craigburke.asset.JavaScriptEngine$run$3.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at com.craigburke.angular.AnnotateProcessor.process(AnnotateProcessor.groovy:27)
        at asset.pipeline.AbstractAssetFile.processedStream(AbstractAssetFile.groovy:164)
        at asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor.fileContents(DirectiveProcessor.groovy:307)
        at asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor$fileContents$2.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at asset.pipeline.AssetPipeline.serveUncompiledAsset(AssetPipeline.groovy:65)
        at asset.pipeline.AssetPipelineFilter.doFilterInternal(AssetPipelineFilter.groovy:175)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    ERROR org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : unable to find resource '/error.vm' in any resource loader.
    ERROR org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager : unable to find resource '/error.vm' in any resource loader.
```

While looking at the network logs in console I can see that all the JS calls are failing with error 500. The template js calls are successfully getting executed though

Comment: Why do you mention velocity? It appears nowhere in the stacktrace.

Comment: If you Google it that's the first suspect. I will also upload the full stack trace

Comment: If you google what?!

Comment: Sorry, for posting incomplete stacktrace but adding the whole message exceeds the allowed length. I have added one more chunk which has the work "Velocity at the end"

Comment: Read carefully the line which contains Velocity: it is unable to find the 'error.vm' template, *during* the handling of the previous error, which appears to be some kind of server-side javascript error. Hence, nothing to do with Velocity.